# Supporting rotation on only a child UIViewController in a hierarchy?

Tags: iphone, orientation, landscape, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a child `UIViewController` with that's part of a hierarchy with a `UITabBarController` and a `UINavigationBarController`. Let's call it `ChildViewController`; then my hierarchy looks like:

```
UITabBarController
  |
  UINavigationViewController [tab 1]
    |
    SomeParentViewController
      |
      SomeOtherParentViewController
        |
        ChildViewController
```

Now I want only `ChildViewController` to support rotation to landscape orientation. (It's a view controller that shows a chat view, and the landscape mode is easier for typing for some.) I added method `- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to `ChildViewController` to declare that it supports landscape orientation, but rotating the device had no effect. From debugging, I found that `– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` wasn't being called.

After some searching around online, I've found that a descendent of a `UITabBarController` only supports a given orientation if the `UITabBarController` itself supports that orientation. And, strangely enough, `UITabBarController` only supports an orientation if the view controllers for each of its tabs support rotation. Like tab 1 above, the view controllers for the other three tabs are `UINavigationViewController` instances; and, because we must go deeper, each `UINavigationViewController` only supports orientation if its child view controller supports the orientation.

So at this point, adding adding `- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to `SomeParentViewController` and the children of the other `UINavigationController` instances allowed `ChildViewController` to rotate. But now `SomeParentViewController` and the other three tabs will rotate to landscape, and it looks horrible. I only wanted  `ChildViewController` to support landscape.

As a latch ditch effort, I created my own `UITabBarController` subclass called `RotatingUITabBarController` and add a global flag to the `ChildViewController` class that lets me know if it has been created and is displayed. The `RotatingUITabBarController` overrides only `- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and is implemented as:

```
if ([ChildViewController isDisplayed]) {
  return ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
      (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
      (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
return NO;
```

Now, if I boot the app, switching to `SomeParentViewController` or any other tab and rotating the phone does not switch to landscape mode, instead keeping in portrait. So far so good. If I create and display `ChildViewController` and rotate the phone, it enters landscape. So far so good. But now if I pop `ChildViewController` to reveal `SomeOtherParentViewController`, it is also in landscape. And so is `SomeParentViewController` and every other tab that I switch to.

I'm out of tricks now. Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best model for the kind of behavior you seem to want is the YouTube app. Most the interface is portrait-only, but the view that plays videos works in either portrait or landscape.

If you look at that app, you'll notice that the whole tabbed part of the UI is actually a modal view controller. When you launch the app, the tab bar controller is immediately presented modally. The only time you leave that modal tab bar controller is when you play a video -- you'll notice that the whole tabbed interface slides down to reveal the video view. When the video ends, the tab bar controller is again presented modally.

This is an inversion of the "normal" approach, where you use a modal view controller only briefly, but it works very well in the YouTube app. It may or may not work well for you too. The important thing is to make your app predictable and fluid, and make the user feel in control at all times.